# Paw hanging forever

Tags: paw-app

I've been using Paw flawlessly for the last two weeks, and is very happy about it.

Today, however, Paw suddenly started hanging and I can't seem to figure out why.

I checked system console and found the following:

```
11/03/16 13:21:49,000 kernel[0]: process Paw[80756] thread 3901396 caught burning CPU! It used more than 50% CPU (Actual recent usage: 95%) over 180 seconds. thread lifetime cpu usage 90.059289 seconds, (87.893506 user, 2.165783 system) ledger info: balance: 90009882091 credit: 90013946094 debit: 4064003 limit: 90000000000 (50%) period: 180000000000 time since last refill (ns): 93974331721 
11/03/16 13:21:53,382 spindump[1310]: Saved cpu_resource.diag report for Paw version 2.3.2 (2003002001) to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Paw_2016-03-11-132153_SkyAir-222.cpu_resource.diag
```

The cpu_resource.diag can be found here: https://gist.github.com/greew/9451a34966371035f019

I've tried force closing the app and opening again, but it hangs immediately after startup.

Does any of you have any idea about what's going on?

Best regards
/Jesper

Comment: I have the same issue however deleting the com.luckymarmot.Paw file didn't work for me.

The issue appeared, when using the file picker in a request. It seems to be a permissions problem.

Any ideas for how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm not using macOS anymore, so I won't be able to help you out here. Hopefully someone else can help :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after few tries, I found that Paw also threw this in the console:

```
11/03/16 13:30:42,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: Paw(80947) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/jesper/Library/Containers/com.luckymarmot.Paw
11/03/16 13:30:42,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: Paw(80947) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/jesper/Library/Containers
11/03/16 13:30:42,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: Paw(80947) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/jesper/Library
11/03/16 13:30:42,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: Paw(80947) deny(1) file-read-data /Users/jesper
11/03/16 13:30:42,000 kernel[0]: Sandbox: Paw(80947) deny(1) file-read-data /Users
```

I tried deleting the /Users/jesper/Library/Containers/com.luckymarmot.Paw folder and now then it worked again (I had to recreate all calls, though).

Comment: This seems very weird. This is a sandbox violation log, I'm wondering if there's anything special with the permissions on your machine? Maybe try a machine restart if that happens again. Also, please save your Paw documents (Cmd + S) in order to keep them safe. Sorry for the inconvenience.